# Warning when defining factor: duplicated levels in factors are deprecated

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

I am having a little trouble with my radar chart in R. Even though the plot is fine I am getting the following warning:

```
> source('~/.active-rstudio-document')
Warning message:
In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
> radar
Warning messages:
1: In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
2: In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
```

I've seen the same error in other posts but I didn't really understand how to apply the answers to my dataset ...

This is my dataset

```
MSF,C1,2
OCA,C1,6
SIOA,C1,4
CCFF,C1,4
MSF,C2,4
OCA,C2,2
SIOA,C2,6
CCFF,C2,2
MSF,C3,6
OCA,C3,6
SIOA,C3,6
CCFF,C3,6
```

And this is the code for the corresponding radar chart (probably only the first part where I define my dataset is relevant but yeah ... that's where I am lost):

```
colnames(dataset) = c("type", "variable", "value")
dataset$value = as.numeric(dataset$value)

dataset$variable <- factor(dataset$variable, levels = rev(dataset$variable), ordered=TRUE)

# Radar function ------------------------------------------------------------
coord_radar <- function (theta = "x", start = 0, direction = 1) {
  theta <- match.arg(theta, c("x", "y"))
  r <- if (theta == "x")
    "y"
  else "x"
  ggproto("CordRadar", CoordPolar, theta = theta, r = r, start = start,
          direction = sign(direction),
          is_linear = function(coord) TRUE)
}


# Radar plot ------------------------------------------------------------
radar <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = variable, y = value, group=type)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group = type, color=type,fill=type), size = 1, alpha=0.1) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette) +
  geom_line(aes(group = type, color=type)) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = cbPalette) + 
  coord_radar()
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes, almost all of that is irrelevant to your problem.

You are trying to create a factor with the following levels: `rev(dataset$variable)`. That yields:

```
[1] C3 C3 C3 C3 C2 C2 C2 C2 C1 C1 C1
```

See how you have replicated levels? You'll want to have each level only once, in the order that you want. The default is `sort(unique(dataset$variable))`, which gives `C1 C2 C3`, or you could use `rev(unique(dataset$variable))` to give `C3 C2 C1`.

The `forcats` package has several convenience functions to easily make or change factors and the order of their levels.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for your response! The line `dataset$variable <- factor(dataset$variable, levels = rev(unique(dataset$variable)), ordered=TRUE)` does it

Comment: @ Jonas, this helped me with a problem I've been having for months. Thank you.