# Reading value labels to spss file in R

Tags: r, label, spss

I use this code to read an spss file:

```
dt<-read.spss("dt.sav",to.data.frame = TRUE,use.value.labels = TRUE)
```

But I got this error:

> Warning message:
>
> In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else
>   paste0(labels,  :   duplicated levels in factors are deprecated

I didn't find anything about it.  Could anyone help me?

Comment: I think you have a variable in your SPSS file were there is a duplicate value label. for example 1 = 'male' 2 = 'female' 3 = 'male'. You should check that in SPSS.

Comment: @Wietze314 i cheked it and i dont have duplicate values but i have two var whit same labels... Can it be because of this?

Comment: Strange I would not expect that. We might need the spss file to understand what is going on

Comment: Take a look at this, it may be the cause of that warning.

[Warning when defining factor: duplicated levels in factors are deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931194/warning-when-defining-factor-duplicated-levels-in-factors-are-deprecated)

Comment: @Wietze314 Hi yes i had a duplicate value label.. but i have new problem now.  My spss dataset have factor (with value labels) and string variables (like cities) when i use use.value.lables=TRUE , all string variables are factor but i dont want it...  i would ask what is the best way to import spss data in R

Comment: I have issues loading SPSS data in R as well, so I have not perfected it yet. Try using the parameter `max.value.labels` option, to prevent heterogeneous string columns to be converted to factors. Otherwise choose to (1) import data without the labels and make factors yourself in R. (2) convert the unwanted factors back to strings with `as.character()`

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, it seems that you have duplicated factors.

You should use:

```
dt<-read.spss("dt.sav",to.data.frame = TRUE,use.value.labels = TRUE,duplicated.value.labels="append")
```