# How to get ggplot2 geom_bar to plot axis by it's factor levels and not by default sorting

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, factors

I would like to make a bar plot in ggplot2 and have ggplot2 graph my X-axis in the same order that I provide in my Day44$Sample column. Here is an example (my real data has 59 factor levels in the Day44$Sample column.

```
Day44 <- data.frame(Sample = c(rep(6, 3), rep(8, 5), rep(12, 8), rep(100, 7), rep("41*", 3), rep("198*", 5)),
                Phylum = c(rep("Proteobacteria", 3), rep("Actinobacteria", 5), rep("Firmicutes", 8), 
                          rep("Chloroflexi", 7), rep("Cyanobacteria", 3), rep("Bacteroidetes", 5)), 
                Rel_Abund = c(rep(2.2, 3), rep(0.15, 5), rep(0.047, 8), rep(1.2, 7), rep(0.33, 3), rep(4.5, 5)))
```

I have read that in order to plot in the same order as my column, I have to 'tell' ggplot2 that I have an ordered factor already - based on this post: [Avoid ggplot sorting the x-axis while plotting geom_bar()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041136/avoid-ggplot-sorting-the-x-axis-while-plotting-geom-bar)

Following the post:

```
Day44$Sample <- factor(Day44$Sample, levels = Day44$Sample)
```

when I get the following error:

> Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = as.character(levels)) : 
>     factor level [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931194/warning-when-defining-factor-duplicated-levels-in-factors-are-deprecated) is duplicated

So, I found this post: [Warning when defining factor: duplicated levels in factors are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931194/warning-when-defining-factor-duplicated-levels-in-factors-are-deprecated)

and following that lead (omitting the `sort` recommended in the post bc I don't need it sorted):

```
Day44$Sample <- factor(Day44$Sample, levels = unique(Day44$Sample)
```

which I then graph with:

```
ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x = Sample, y = Rel_Abund, fill = Phylum), data = Day44, stat = 'identity')
```

And it gives me a nice bar plot, however; the x-axis is sorted anyway. 
[image: Bar Plot]

This piece of code clues me into the error, which gives:

```
factor(unique(Day44$Sample))
```

> 6    8    12   100  41*  198*
>
> Levels: 100 12 198* 41* 6 8

How can I change this to where my levels are in the same order as my unique values for Day44$Sample?

I know I can manually put them in, like this:

```
Day44$Sample <- factor(Day44$Sample, levels = c("6", "8", "12", "100", "41*", "198*"))
```

producing the exact graph that I want, but this isn't practical, since my real data has 59 levels and I have to do this with multiple other graphs, too. I'll never finish doing this manually.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to order your factor levels based on the order they appear in the dataframe, use `forcats::fct_inorder`:

```
Day44$Sample = forcats::fct_inorder(Day44$Sample)
```

Comment: Thinking about this again, `Day44$Sample <- factor(Day44$Sample, levels = unique(Day44$Sample))` should have worked - it may be worth trying that again to double check your understanding.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I installed the package `forcats` and ran the code, and it worked beautifully! Thank-you.